# delete duplicate strings in a Linkedhashmap

Tags: java, string, collections

i have a linked hash map

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap();
```

whose keyset and values are

```
50,Tam,medicine = 7
50,Pep,surgery = 3
50,Tam,surgery = 6 
50,Ery,treatment = 2
60,cap,treatment = 3
60,syn,treatment = 5
60,syn,surgery = 6
60,pep,surgery = 5
60,pep,medicine = 3
```

i need to group it based on first string i.e str[0]. then delete keyset whose either str[1] or str[2] are repeated and has highest value. some thing like arrange it in ascending order and delete keyset whose str[1] or str[2] are repeated and having highest value.

final output should be

```
50,Ery,treatment=2
50,Pep,surgery=3
50,Tam,surgery=6 //should be deleted as in group 50 "surgery" is repeated above
50,Tam,medicine=7
60,cap,treatment=3
60,pep,medicine=3
60,pep,surgery=5 //should be deleted as in group 60 "pep" is repeated above 
60,syn,treatment=5 //should be deleted as in group 60 "treatment" is repeated above
60,syn,surgery=6 

public static LinkedHashMap sortHashMapByValuesD(Map passedMap) {
        List mapKeys = new ArrayList(passedMap.keySet());
        List mapValues = new ArrayList(passedMap.values());
        Map<String, Integer> dUnique = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        Collections.sort(mapValues);
        Collections.sort(mapKeys);

        LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap();

        Iterator valueIt = mapValues.iterator();
        while (valueIt.hasNext()) {
            Object val = valueIt.next();
            Iterator keyIt = mapKeys.iterator();

            while (keyIt.hasNext()) {
                Object key = keyIt.next();
                String comp1 = passedMap.get(key).toString();
                String comp2 = val.toString();

                if (comp1.equals(comp2)) {
                    passedMap.remove(key);
                    mapKeys.remove(key);
                    sortedMap.put((String) key, (Integer) val);
                    break;
                }

            }

        }
        for (String sorted : sortedMap.keySet()) {
            String[] dsort = sorted.split(",");
           // System.out.println(sorted + sortedMap.get(sorted));


            if (dUnique.get(dsort[0]) == null) {
                dUnique.put(sorted, sortedMap.get(sorted));
                System.out.println(dUnique.keySet());
            } else {
                for (int i = 1; i < dsort.length; i++) {
                    if (dUnique.get(dsort[i]) == null) {
                        dUnique.put(sorted, sortedMap.get(sorted));
                    } else {
                        dUnique.remove(sorted);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(dUnique.keySet());
        return sortedMap;
    }
```

Comment: i first sorted it in ascending order, then grouped based on the first element then i tried to delete the keyset.

Comment: But there's no problem to solve here; you've only asked for a solution. If you want help faster, you need to ask specific questions about what's wrong with the solution you had and what error messages there are (if any).

Comment: it doesnt give any output. i'm not sure if my logic is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This code may help you :

```
public static LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> sortHashMapByValuesD(LinkedHashMap passedMap) {
    LinkedHashMap  temp = passedMap;
    LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> dUnique = new LinkedHashMap();
    Iterator it=temp.keySet().iterator();
    Map hp = new HashMap();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        String key = (String)it.next();
        String preKey =   key.substring(0,key.lastIndexOf(",") );
        if( !hp.containsKey(preKey) ){
            dUnique.put(key, (Integer)temp.get(key));
        }
        hp.put(preKey,preKey);
    }

    return dUnique;

}
```

good luck.